# Cypress get the ID of some element

Tags: cypress

I am trying to obtain the ID of some element in Cypress. Because it's ID randomly changes (yes it is strange but it is angular).

E.g. I have a `<button id="dropdown-1" class="someclass"><span>Click here</button>`

As I can't rely on that ID, because after I do some actions on the page it becomes to dropdown-2 etc., I want to know, what is the current ID name.

I tried something like:

```
cy.get('button > span').contains('Click here').find("id");
```

but seems that is not the correct way.

I also tried:

```
  cy.get('button > span').contains('Click here')
  .invoke('attr', 'id')
```

this works not as well.

Comment: Use e.g. https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro then you can select it by role, rather than relying on something that's irrelevant to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of text and a selector which has the non-changing part of your id value. Something like:

```js
cy.contains('button[id*="dropdown-"]', 'Click here').invoke('attr', 'id')
```

Now you can use use the id value in two ways.

1. Directly after extraction:

```js
cy.contains('button[id*="dropdown-"]', 'Click here')
  .invoke('attr', 'id')
  .then((id) => {
    cy.log(id) //prints id
  })
```

2. Save it in alias `.as` and use it later:

```js
cy.contains('button[id*="dropdown-"]', 'Click here')
  .invoke('attr', 'id')
  .as('idValue')
cy.get('@idValue').then((idValue) => {
  cy.log(idvalue) //prints id
})
```

Comment: this way it works, but how can I work with that ID which is returned? I used it like invoke('attr', 'id').as('ide'); but when I log ide says not defined

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you check?

Comment: ah I forgot to use then(). Your solution is excellent, thank you!